# Lambda Error: '>' not supported - But did not use '>' - Converting function to lambda

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

I'm attempting to convert the initial code I wrote into a lambda function. I'm new to using lambda, so I would appreciate any insight here as to why this isn't working.

I know my method likely isn't the most efficient way of solving. I'm still a novice coder and learning :)

If you are able to help me convert this code into a lambda, I would appreciate it. I don't need a "better" solution, because this problem is from codewars.com which offers multiple, more elegant solutions from users.

My initial code:

```
def high(x):
    letters = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    res = [sum([letters.index(l) for l in y]) for y in x.split()]

    return x.split()[res.index(max(res))]

high('man i need a taxi up to ubud')
```

My attempt at lambda:

```
def high(x):
    letters = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    res = max(x.split(), lambda k: sum(letters.index(z) for z in k))
    return res
```

Which gives:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'list'
```

For reference, here is the most upvoted solution that I'm trying to emulate without using ord().

```
def high(x):
    return max(x.split(), key=lambda k: sum(ord(c) - 96 for c in k))
```

This has me confused because I'm not using a '>'.

Thanks!

Comment: You are not using `>`, but `max()` does internally.

Comment: What would be the difference between my code, and the "right" code? Both use max()

Comment: In the 'right' code the lambda function assigns a return value to a variable. In your code you are trying to compare a value with a reference to the lambda function.

Comment: Okay, starting to make sense. Thank you. Would there still be a way to get the sum of the index within lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how I didn't notice this. I forgot to add "key=". My function works now.

```
def high(x):
    letters = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    return max(x.split(), key=lambda k: sum(letters.index(z) for z in k))

high('man i need a taxi up to ubud')
```

Comment: Correct, and instead of posting an answer, I'd recommend closing the question, since it's basically a typo

Answer (score -1):

To give the lambda function some data, you need to map it to your dataset, x.split() in this case. `

```
def high(x):
    letters = " abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    res = list(map(lambda k: sum(letters.index(z) for z in k),x.split()))
    return x.split()[res.index(max(res))]
```